# React js problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help with reactJS. I have a task to write a code. When a user opens this code, (s)he sees a button to send another user to a game. When I click this button, I see 2 buttons decline invintation or accept.

But my browser shows empty page.

this is my code:

```
<div id = "gameInterface"></div>

<script type = "text/babel">
    var gameInterface = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return {document.getElementsByClassName('send')}
        },
        render: function(){
            if (document.getElementById('send').state.onclick){
                document.getElementById('decline') && document.getElementById(accept).value;
            }
        },
        buttonToSendInvintation: function(){
           return (
                <div>
                    <button className = 'send'>Send invintation to play to another user</button>
                </div>
           ) 
        },
        buttonToAceptOrDeclineInvintation: function(){
           return (
                <div>
                    <p>Some user sent you an invintation</p>
                    <button className = 'accept'>Accept</button>
                    <button className = 'decline'>Decline</button>
                </div>
           ); 
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<gameInterface />, document.getElementById("gameInterface"));
</script>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In react, custom components must be in PascalCase, not camelCase. If the babel jsx transpiler sees an element that starts with a lower-case letter (i.e. in 'gameInterface'), it will transpile it to:

```
React.createElement("gameInterface", null);
```

instead of what you're hoping for:

```
React.createElement(gameInterface, null);
```

which is a reference to the class you created. React does this is to differentiate between native DOM elements and custom components. Capitalize your component names and you'll get the right behavior:

```
var GameInterface = React.createClass({
    ...
})

ReactDOM.render(<GameInterface />, document.getElementById("gameInterface"));
```